# How to show header side bar again after ajax call response in app component

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-cognito

I am hitting following AWS api for fetching user information based on access token (after some calculation in app.component.ts).

```
this.cognitoidentityserviceprovider.getUser({"AccessToken":accToken},
                    function(err, data){
             // bind this data to header 
});
```

I want api return data to be bound to header bar but header component rendered earlier and i am not able to re-rendered again.
My routing structure as follows in layout.component.html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- top navbar-->
    <app-header class="topnavbar-wrapper"></app-header>
    <!-- sidebar-->
    <app-sidebar class="aside"></app-sidebar>
    <!-- Main section-->
    <section>
        <!-- Page content-->
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Page footer-->
    <footer app-footer></footer>
</div>
```

Comment: can you call the api in header component itself  ?

Comment: Can't call in header component.App component is first component where i do some calculation and then after hit the ajax call which take some time and header rendered before which cause problem.
I tried to re rendered header again once ajax call return response.
But this is not able to  happen in angular.
I worked on both AngularJS and reactjs and with these it can be possible

Comment: you can use @Input for headerComponent : https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: i tried the same but it is not updating the value in child component.
Can you please write the code here which work.
This is first time i am trying angular 2. I am completely new for this technology

Answer (score 1):

Code in app.component.html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- top navbar-->
    <app-header class="topnavbar-wrapper" [apiresponse]="apidata"></app-header>
    <!-- sidebar-->
    <app-sidebar class="aside"></app-sidebar>
    <!-- Main section-->
    <section>
        <!-- Page content-->
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Page footer-->
    <footer app-footer></footer>
</div>
```

In app.component.ts

```
let self = this ;
apidata:any = "";
this.cognitoidentityserviceprovider.getUser({"AccessToken":accToken},
                    function(err, data){
     // bind this data to header 
     self.apidata = data;
});
```

In header.component.ts

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() apiresponse : any;
  //your code here  
}
```

In header.component.html use {{apiresponse}}

Comment: Following is layout.component.html

<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- top navbar-->
    <app-header class="topnavbar-wrapper" [apiresponse]="apidata"></app-header>
 -------

App.component.html

<router-outlet ></router-outlet>

My simple concern how to pass data from router-outlet to layout.component.ts which re-rendered header,siderbar again